# ASP.NET WebAPI + Durandal SPA + Glimpse

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, durandal, glimpse

What's the exact recipe I need to get Glimpse working on a JavaScript-powered Single Page Application when I'm using WebAPI as the server end (i.e. all ajax requests rather than form POSTs)?

Answer (score 1):

**Standalone Glimpse page**

http://blog.markvincze.com/use-glimpse-with-asp-net-web-api/

In order to be able to use Glimpse independently from the web page itself, it also supports a standalone view, that can also be accessed from its /Glimpse.axd configuration page.
On this page we can see a list of all the requests coming to our application, let them be MVC or WebApi requests.